# Does "How will you use this SD card?" wipe data?

Tags: external-sd, lineageos, android-10

There is a notification almost every time after boot saying "Issue with SD card" "Tap to Fix".

What happens when I then choose "Use as portable storage"?

I don't want any formatting to happen and it is not clear if it will format or not. ( My SD card works fine from recovery and I can mount and view it in the terminal without problem. Not sure what the notification is about. )

Comment: Yes it reformats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now backed up my contents and am able to try this out.

[image: screenshot of "how will you use this SD card?"]
[image: popup after choosing "portable storage"]

The popup indeed makes it clear that data will be lost.

---

#### Process

If, like me, you don't believe the system that your card is broken, you can try running `fsck` like @alecxs advised me to. Use the `-y` flag to avoid manually confirming every fix.

I used `mount`/`blkid` to see what filesystemtype my SDcard uses and what its block device id is. And then I ran `fsck.exfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1` which told me

```
1|beryllium:/ # fsck.exfat -V /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
exfatfsck 1.2.2
Copyright (C) 2011-2015  Andrew Nayenko
beryllium:/ # fsck.exfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
exfatfsck 1.2.2
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for posixrules!
WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
Checking file system on /dev/block/mmcblk0p1.
File system version           1.0
Sector size                 512 bytes
Cluster size                128 KB
Volume size                 463 GB
Used space                  211 GB
Available space             252 GB
ERROR: unknown entry type 0x89.

ERROR: unexpected continuation (0).
Totally 5536 directories and 64646 files.
File system checking finished. ERRORS FOUND: 2.
```

**whoops, I should have unmounted it first!!**

Running it again (this time from boot instead of recovery (shouldn't matter), and not mounted) I get the option to actually fix it. Note that I did this as `su`:

```
beryllium:/ # fsck.exfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
exfatfsck 1.3.0
Checking file system on /dev/block/mmcblk0p1.
File system version           1.0
Sector size                 512 bytes
Cluster size                128 KB
Volume size                 463 GB
Used space                  211 GB
Available space             252 GB
ERROR: unknown entry type 0xc0.
Fix (Y/N)? Y
ERROR: unknown entry type 0xc1.
Fix (Y/N)? Y
ERROR: unknown entry type 0xc1.
Fix (Y/N)? Y
Totally 5537 directories and 64860 files.
File system checking finished. ERRORS FOUND: 3, FIXED: 3.
reboot
```

The reboot was fairly quick, the login afterwards took a bit of time, and now... the sd card warning is gone! This also answers a question I was already typing but haven't submitted yet: How to fix the SD card without data loss!
<sup><sub>I shall publish that question as well soon, so that it's easier to find this solution.</sub></sup>

Comment: @alecxs thank you! Thought I'd let you know that this helped!